# In Postgres, how do I adjust the "pgsql_tmp" setting?

Tags: postgresql, disk-space, temporary-tables

I"m using Postgres 9.5.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.  I have my Postgres data on a separate disk partiion, which is getting pretty full.

```
myuser@myproject:~$ df -h /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda 99G 93G 413M 100% /mnt/volume-nyc1-01
```

I want to delete some data from my partition, but this has become challenging.  In particular, when I run some queries, i get results like this

```
myproject_production=> select count(*) FROM my_object_times rt1, my_object_times rt2 where rt1.my_object_id = rt2.my_object_id and rt1.name = rt2.name and rt1.time_in_ms = rt2.time_in_ms and rt1.id > rt2.id;;
ERROR:  could not write block 52782 of temporary file: No space left on device
```

I want to free up some temp space so I can run queries and identify what data I need to delete.  I have some other free space on another partition. How do I point my pgsql_tmp variable there so that I can run the queries I need?

**Edit:**

As the symlink option seemed to be the least invasive, I gave it a go, setting up things like this

```
myuser@myproject:~$ sudo ls -al /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/postgresql/9.5/main/base/pgsql_tmp
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Apr 10 18:01 /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/postgresql/9.5/main/base/pgsql_tmp -> /opt/pgsql_tmp
myuser@myproject:~$ cd /opt
myuser@myproject:/opt$ df -h /
Filesystem                                              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/disk/by-uuid/050e1e34-39e6-4072-a03e-ae0bf90ba13a   40G   24G   15G  62% /
```

You can see that I have over 16GB available on the partition where I pointed it to, but still I get the errors

```
ERROR:  could not write block 1862514 of temporary file: No space left on device
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TEMP-TABLESPACES)

> `temp_tablespaces` (string)
>   
>   This variable specifies tablespaces in which to create temporary objects (temp tables and indexes on temp tables) when a CREATE command does not explicitly specify a tablespace. Temporary files for purposes such as sorting large data sets are also created in these tablespaces.

In order to be able to use that, you need to create a tablespace on that volume, create a directory there (owned by the `postgres` user!), then run this:

```
create tablespace temp_space LOCATION 'mnt/volume-nyc1-01/pg_temp';
```

You need to grant the necessary privileges on that tablespace:

```
grant create on tablespace temp_space to public;
```

After that you can e.g. use

```
alter system set temp_tablespaces=temp_space;
```

(alternatively you could just change that in your session)

Note that for the `alter system` to have any effect, you need to reload the configuration:

```
select pg_reload_conf();
```

---

Alternatively just change the `$PGDATA/base/pgsql_tmp` to be a symbolic link to the directory on the other partition.

Comment: I edited my question to show the restuls of running the symlink option.  Despite pointing the directory to a different partition, I still get the "could not write block 1862514 of temporary file: No space left on device" error.

Comment: Please disregard my comment.  The query was causing so much data to be generated, even my other partition wasn't big enough.

Comment: Thank you for including the `grant` statement. No other guide has it, and it's essential.